# ERROR: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to update the  Android Gradle plugin but Im getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31.
```

Those are the lines I added to update the Android Gradle plugin (build.gradle file):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Gradle 4.1 and higher include support for Google's Maven repo using
        // the google() method. And you need to include this repo to download
        // Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are missing some repositories(*jcenter*) and some dependencies(*kotlin-gradle-plugin*). That's why Kotlin cannot be found.

Your `build.gradle(Project:android)` file should look something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: what does the "task clean..." code do in the file?  Should that be in every project/app?